# Varying performance of Oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, oracle11g, query-optimization

I have a query which joins a table to some data dictionary views. The query works correctly sometimes, but sometimes it takes too long to execute. When it does so, it does not respond even if I cancel and run it 100 times again.

The query is :

```
 SELECT
      /*+  PARALLEL(auto) */
     t.id
    FROM table1 t ,
        (SELECT     /*+  PARALLEL(auto) */ DISTINCT r.INDEX_VALUE AS id,
          r.LOCAL_ROWID,
          r.REMOTE_ROWID
        FROM DBA_COMPARISON_COLUMNS c,
          DBA_COMPARISON_ROW_DIF r,
          DBA_COMPARISON_SCAN s
        WHERE R.SCAN_ID       = S.SCAN_ID
        AND c.COMPARISON_NAME = 'CMP_name'
        AND s.root_SCAN_ID    = '{scan_id}'
        AND r.STATUS          = 'DIF'
        ) dif
      WHERE t.id = dif.id;
```

Could anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: It's impossible to answer a question phrased like this. Please share the query and the error you get when the query doesn't work.

Comment: Why is this question upvoted twice ? This question doesn't even have code to look at.

Comment: The query does not have error, It takes too  long when I run It so I cancel it.

Comment: Can you please share the query ?

Comment: If you read the question, I said It is a simple join. If anyone had the same problem help me.

Comment: http://tkyte.blogspot.de/2005/06/how-to-ask-questions.html

Comment: @PirateX : I shared the query.

Comment: And lo! once you posted the query it turns out a "simple join between two tables" is actually a join between a table and an in-line view joining three data dictionary view. Not so simple after all. Next time you ask a question please consider posting all the relevant information at the outset instead of making people drag it out of you. Help us to help you.

Answer (score 1):

There can be 100 reasons why your query keeps running, depending (but not limited to) your database, other tables writing data to same table, locks on the table etc.

You should fist check v$session_longops views to see if this query is there and some other details.

I generally use below for troubleshooting. You can check if your query is there. If yes, find the `sid` and backtrack it to views to check for lock etc.

```
select sesion.sid,sql_text
from v$sqltext sqltext, v$session sesion
where sesion.sql_hash_value = sqltext.hash_value
and sesion.sql_address = sqltext.address
and sesion.username is not null
order by sqltext.piece;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query is based on views which show output from DBMS_COMPARISON. So the size of the result set will vary according to the delta generated by the comparison. If there's a lot of drift the delta could be very large because you are querying for the row differences.

One other potential problem: your query doesn't join DBA_COMPARISON_COLUMNS to the other tables. Probably you should include COMPARISON_NAME in the join criteria, like this...

```
FROM DBA_COMPARISON_COLUMNS c,
      DBA_COMPARISON_ROW_DIF r,
      DBA_COMPARISON_SCAN s
    WHERE c.COMPARISON_NAME = 'CMP_name'
    AND r.COMPARISON_NAME = c.COMPARISON_NAME
    AND s.COMPARISON_NAME = c.COMPARISON_NAME
    AND R.SCAN_ID       = S.SCAN_ID
    AND s.root_SCAN_ID    = '{scan_id}'
    AND r.STATUS          = 'DIF'
```